# Git ignore subfolder presents in every subfolder

Tags: git

I want to ignore the content changes of a subfolder presents in every folders of my directory.

```
Folder1
 |--- Thumbs
      |---thumb1.png
          thumb2.png
Folder2
 |---- Thumbs
       |--- thumb1.png
Folder4
 |--- Thumbs
      |--- thumb1.png
      |--- thumb2.png
 .gitignore
 .gitkeep
```

I can't find the exact condition to put in `.gitignore` file. Any help is really appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Then write your entry without a slave in front of the line or use the `*` as wildcard. For example if you try to ignore the `Thumbs` folder. Then you can use.

```
/*/Thumbs/
```

or

```
Thumbs
```

But the second one can cause problem then all files and folder with the word `Thumbs` in it will be ignored. So better use the first version.

https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: At the end I did as follow: `/**/Thumbs/**`. Thanks for the your suggestion!!

Comment: That would be the same as `Thumbs/`, because you match the root, then any directory depth, then a directory called `Thumbs` and then all content. The same does `Thumbs/` which means a directory called `Thumbs` and its contents, anyhwere down in the directory tree.